# MacBook Air 2015 no chime no boot

Tags: macbook-pro

Hi everyone my MacBook Air a1466 2015 wont chime or boot when ssd is connected but when I remove d ssd it chimes and boot up to the question mark folder as normal. I have tried four known working ssd and same thing happens. I have tried resetting smc and pram and still does not boot up.

Comment: Perhaps the ribbon cable, connecting the SSDs inside the MBA has been damaged.

Comment: The ssd is inserted directly to the motherboard